# Proof of employment for a Schengen Visa from French Consulate Vancouver?

Tags: visas, schengen, proof-of-employment

On its website, it requires some format of proof of employment.
However, no-one in my family has that.

I am a student, my brother (another applicant) is currently unemployed, my mom (another applicant) is currently unemployed, and my father (who is currently in China) is employed but I don't know how we can get that in Canada.

We have enough usable financial support and own a property.

What document do I need and what's the odd of getting rejected? We are all Chinese citizen with Canadian PR.

Answer (score 2):

The requirements are really having sufficient financial means for the trip and for the return to your country of residence and presenting sufficient guarantees that you will not try to immigrate illegally. Employment is not necessary *per se* and an employment contract is but one type of supporting documentation you can use to show that you fulfil the requirements.

Beyond that, it depends on what you mean by financial support and I have no idea what your odds are. Millionaires don't have problems getting visas, but having only a few thousands euros with no job and no other ties to Canada might not be enough. On the other hand, property and Canadian PR are good so that's a start.

Comment: Socio-professional status and legal status in Canada are two separate requirements on their list. Having PR only means he's legally allowed to return

Comment: @Blackbird57 Yes, but it also means you had to qualify for it and you already have access to a first-world country, which makes you less of a “risk” than someone on some temporary visa or living back in your country of origin. That's why I think it's good. The actual requirement behind all this is intending to leave the Schengen area, incidentally, not socio-professional status per se either so other ties (family for example) can also help.

Answer (score 1):

You can find the detailed list of requirements [here](http://www.consulfrance-vancouver.org/Short-stay-visa-for-tourism-for#requirements-4)

In short, you need

- A valid passport
- The filled form
- The processing fee
- Two pictures
- Travel itinerary
- Proof of accomodation
- Documents supporting your status in Canada (your PR card typically)
- Last 3 bank statements
- Travel insurance
- Proof of status in Canada

This last one is important, they're looking for significant ties here that you will come back for. If you're a student you can submit a letter from your school/university. They have a provision for unemployment too, I think they're more interested in ties in Canada than financial means in this case.

I think your family who lives in China will have to apply in China.

You have to fulfill all their requirements but it doesn't guarantee acceptance, I can't comment on the odds as it's entirely up to them to decide

Comment: Maybe that's nitpicking but fulfilling the requirements does not merely increase your chances, it's absolutely necessary (and, although that's somewhat debatable, mostly sufficient). If you can get a visa without something, it's not requirement. Employment is not for example, it's just one way to satisfy the actual requirements.

Comment: @Relaxed you're right, updated answer